# HAProxy change header

Tags: haproxy

I want to configure my HAProxy (V1.7) to change the Location-field in the header of the server-response before sending it back to the client. I tried various options but wasn't able to get the right result. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your haproxy.conf look like?   Add it to the question.